# Following different tables in a leader database in different follower databases

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I try to manage view access to multiple tables in my ADX database. Each table should be accessed by different users.

I have created a follower database in a separate cluster that follows only one table as described in [Manage view access to tables within the same database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/manage-table-view-access#create-a-follower-database).

However, if I try to add another follower database in the same follower cluster, to allow access to another table, the deployment fails with

```
{
  "code": "Failed",
  "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Is there a possibility to have multiple follower databases, that follow different tables of the same leader database, all in the same follower cluster?

Answer (score 0):

*"I try to manage view access to multiple tables in my ADX database. Each table should be accessed by different users."*

Maybe it is an option for you to stay on just one cluster and use a row level access policy instead of different follower clusters for implementing a user separation. You might create a RLS function which queries the users or AAD user groups. There is an example in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy) for this use case:

```
let UserToCountryMapping = datatable(User:string, Country:string)
[
  "john@domain.com", "USA",
  "anna@domain.com", "France"
];
Sales
| where Country in ((UserToCountryMapping | where User == current_principal_details()["UserPrincipalName"] | project Country))
```

This approach works also for AAD groups instead of single users:

```
let isinGroup1 =  
current_principal_is_member_of('aadgroup=RX999-C-SYNCH_USERGROUP1;4711azz-110zz-7b8d-325b-ferfeferf012')
```

I experienced that this is approach is less costly and more convenient.